# Implement social buttons on unlimited/infinite scrolling website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2, social-networking, share-button

I'm using jquery [social-likes plugin](https://github.com/sapegin/social-likes/) to implement social buttons on index page of my ruby on rails based website. This index page is infinitely scrollable, when the new content is loaded, this newly loaded item doesn't display any social buttons.
How can I make re-rendering of these social buttons when the new item is loaded on runtime.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you supply a link to the website?

Comment: @Ryan using $('.social-likes').socialLikes(); solved it.